# How do I edit/delete MySQL backups in Webmin

Tags: webmin

I'm using Webmin.  I set up a recurring backup of some MySQL (MariaDB, actually) databases using the Webmin Mysql management tool.
They're working, but I don't see a way to modify or delete those backup jobs.  What am I missing?